# How can I not show the open dialog first?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

Well, the only problem I am having is that the open dialog is showing first. What I want is to only to put it inside the `JFrame` and then do the rest inside the `JFrame` like opening image and display it. [It should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7334J.png)

The problem is that my `JFileChooser` is showing first. And also the thing is I want it all to be inside the JFrame just like in the image shown.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class imgviewer extends JFrame{
    
    JButton button;
    JLabel label;
    
    public imgviewer() {
        super("Image viewer");
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(400, 10, 180, 300);
        Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 2);
        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser(".");
        label.setBorder(b);
        add(label);
        file.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        
        file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg", "png", "gif");
        file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            int result = file.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
                String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                label.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
            }
                
            else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("No File Selected");
            }
        
        add(file);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(600, 350);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
     public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String ImagePath) {
         ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(ImagePath);
         Image img = MyImage.getImage();
         Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImg);
         return image;
     }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new imgviewer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do what you want to do, but where you put the line `int result = file.showOpenDialog(null);` into your code, that's a line that explicitly means "open this JFileChooser in its own file dialog NOW". In the order of your code, that clearly happens before the `setVisible(true)` line which would open the wrapper you wish to put around the file dialog.

Is there a reason the code after `file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);`, and before `add(file)`, is indented? If you were imagining that this code is in a separate block which will prevent it from being executed until later, it isn't.

I haven't worked with `JFileChooser`, or Swing in general, for a long time now, so I don't know off hand how well a `JFileChooser` will work if treated as a separate component embedded inside another component, but if that's going to work at all, you definitely cannot use `JFileChooser`'s `showOpenDialog` method.

Comment: Yes, I think that was the problem. I was wondering if there is a way to embed it inside the `jframe`. The `add(file);` was to show the open dialog inside a jframe so that I can show what should be the output but what I am getting wrong here is that I don't know why the dialog is showing first.

Comment: Like I said, as soon as the line `int result = file.showOpenDialog(null);` executes, the dialog will appear. In your code, that happens before the `setVisible(true)` that you execute to open your own wrapper dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: I'm not even sure if what you're trying to do can be done -- JFileDialog was primarily designed to operate as an independent dialog rather than as a component embedded within another component. If this is going to work, I suspect you'll have to do something like make your own subclass of JDialog where you override the `approveSelection()` and `cancelSelection()` methods so there're a way to detect when the user selects a file (or cancels) without calling `showOpenDialog()` to get that result.